# Log4J - Logger don't work

Tags: log4j, appender

I use Log4J for an Java Application.

Please find an extract of my log4j.xml file next:

```
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

   <logger name="my.package.name">
     <priority value="debug" />
   </logger>
```

I want to print each log with a `info` level and `debug` logs for my package `my.package.name`.
But, these `debug` logs don't appear... :(

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
```

to

```
    <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
```

Since you have placed `Threshold` to `INFO` only `info and above` will logged . Debug level is below info level. So that is why debug levels are not logged.

log4j hierarchy is `TRACE Level < DEBUG Level< INFO Level< WARN Level < ERROR Level < FATAL Level`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay. But is there a possibility to print only debug for a specified package and info for the other package ?

Comment: Yes you can create different loggers for different packages where you can specify the level of logging as well

Comment: But, if one the loggers has a lower level than the Appender threshold, does it print logs ?

Comment: logger pushes the logs to the appenders based on the level it is set in logger configuration and appenders write to say a file or console based on the level appender is set at . so if appender threshold is more than level at logger level , the above issue will occur

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you should mark it as answered and close the post